# How to get last 5 posts title of taxonomy?

Tags: wordpress, schema, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I have a coupon website and I want to add schema on my coupon store page. suppose I have an amazon store and added 5 coupon posts on amazon. Now, I want to add these 5 post titles and post links to the schema. could you please tell me how can I do it?

Below is my code:

```php
<script type="application/ld+json">{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@graph": [
        {
           "@type": "WebPage",
            "url": "<?php echo esc_html($taglink);?>",
            "image": {
                "@type": "ImageObject",
                "url": "<?php echo esc_html($brandimage);?>",
                "height": 100,
                "width": 170
            },
            "publisher": {
                "@type": "Organization",
                "name": "Coupon.com",
                "logo": {
                    "@type": "ImageObject",
                    "url": "https://cdn.coupontac.com/ovowhakr/2020/10/Logo.png.webp",
                    "width": 500,
                    "height": 200
                }
            },
            "dateModified": "",
            "description":"<?php echo esc_html($schemdesc2);?>",
            "name": "",
            "headline":"<?php echo esc_html($heading);?>",
            "mainEntity": {
                "@context": "http://schema.org",
                "@type": "Store",
                "name": "<?php echo esc_html($tagname);?>",
                "image": "<?php echo esc_html($brandimage);?>",
                "sameAs": "<?php echo esc_html($weburl);?>",
                
                "aggregateRating": {
                        "@type": "AggregateRating",
                        "ratingValue": <?php echo esc_html($userrating);?>,
                        "ratingCount": <?php echo esc_html($ratingcount);?>,
                        "bestRating": 5,
                        "worstRating": 0
                },
                "description": "<?php echo esc_html($schemdesc);?>",
                "makesOffer": [
                {
                        "@type": "Offer",
                        "name": "",
                        "url": "",
                        "description": "",
                        "validFrom": "",
                        "validThrough": ""  
        },
                ]
            }
            
        }
        
    ]
}</script>
```

can any one help me to get 5 post title on below section ?

```php
 "makesOffer": [
                {
                        "@type": "Offer",
                        "name": "",
                        "url": "",
                        "description": "",
                        "validFrom": "",
                        "validThrough": ""  
        },
                ]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you tried so far? please put in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would simply query through the required post from the `<head>`, but instead of using an html template you would use a schema one.

As you already showed in your example, PHP can go inside javascript as it is server based, it is rendered first.

You can't use `"makesOffer"` or any unique key multiple times. You have to repeat the offer.

You can test your structured data online against [Google own data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/).

The following is based on the [`makesOffer` schema.org page example](https://schema.org/makesOffer).

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
[
<?php
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
//...
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
while( $query->have_posts() ) :
$query->the_post(); ?>
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Person",
  "name" : "Brent",
  "makesOffer" : {
        "@type" :"Offer",
        "priceSpecification" : {
            "@type" : "UnitPriceSpecification",
            "priceCurrency" : "USD",
            "price" : "18000" },
        "itemOffered" : {
            "@type" : "Car",
            "name" : "<?= wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_title(), true ); ?>",
            "description" : "<?= wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_excerpt(), true ); ?>",
        "image" : "2009_Volkswagen_Golf_V_GTI_MY09.png",
        "color" : "Black",
        "numberOfForwardGears" : "6",
        "vehicleEngine" : {
            "@type": "EngineSpecification",
            "name" : "4 cylinder Petrol Turbo Intercooled 2.0 L (1984 cc)"
            }
        }
    }
},
<?php endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
]
</script>
```

Comment: I add this code and works perfectly fine as I want but I have a problem that I want to display particular taxonomy posts, not the last posts. so can it be possible?

Comment: @JackWhite you can build a custom query by passing arguments through. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.